# having problems publishing with web deploy with VS2013 but not VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

We have moved from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013 and take make thing more complicated, we moved tfs servers. I note the second part since that allows me to still test the 2010 code and see that I don't have any issues publishing. When I try to publish with 2013 I'm getting this message:

[image]

These are the settings I successfully deploy with on 2010:

[image]

These are the settings I attempt with 2013:

[image]

As you can see from the checkmark, it validates with these settings.

Initially 2013 brought over my profile from 2010. I ended up deleting that profile and creating a new one to see if that resolved it.

This is the settings screen in case if helps any:

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm stuck and I have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per this post: [Visual Studio 2013 Web Deploy fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669796/visual-studio-2013-web-deploy-fails?rq=1)

I took a shot and renamed the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Targets to .old and then reran the upload. I got past this error though I got another one not related to this issue.

Hope this helps someone!